# If the sets $A=\{x\in E, f(x)<\lambda\}$ and $B=\{x\in E, f(x)>\lambda\}$ are open, then $f$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I have that $f: (E,\theta)\rightarrow (\mathbb{R},|.|)$ an application, if we have that for all $\lambda\in \mathbb{R}$ the two sets $A=\{x\in E, f(x)<\lambda\}$ and $B=\{x\in E, f(x)>\lambda\}$ are open.

How to prove that f is continuous?

Can I say that $A=f^{-1}(]-\infty,\lambda[)$ and $B=f^{-1}(]\lambda,+\infty[)$ then the preimage of an open sets is open so $f$ is continuous.

But why we have to use the two sets $A$ and $B$ ?

Thank you

Comment: This proof is not correct. For example you missed to prove that $f^{-1}(]0,1[)$ is open. You should prove that for EVERY open set $U \subset \Bbb{R}$ you have $f^{-1}(U)$ is open: you have information about some open sets (i.e. unbounded intervals), can you get some information about all oepn sets?

Comment: i have no idea about all open sets , i justs have A and B for all $\lambda $

Answer (score 2):

Let $U$ open in $(\mathbb{R},|\cdot|)$. If $U=\emptyset$ or $U=\mathbb{R}$, then  a straightforward argument shows $f^{-1}(U)\in\theta$.

Now, let $(a,b)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. If we prove that $f^{-1}((a,b))\in\theta$, we finish.

But $(a,b)=(-\infty,b)\cap(a,\infty)$. Then $f^{-1}(a,b)=f^{-1}((-\infty,b)\cap(a,\infty))=f^{-1}((-\infty,b))\cap f^{-1}((a,\infty))$.

Now, by hypothesis, both of $f^{-1}((-\infty,b))$ and $f^{-1}((a,\infty))$ are open, and since finite intersection of open sets is an open set, $f^{-1}(a,b)$ is open.

Comment: if $U=\emptyset$ then $f^{-1}(U)=\emptyset$ right ?, $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})=E$ ? thank you

Comment: That's correct. Indeed, generaly don't prove it cause is a triviality. But it seems that you're new in topology. So, It is better you have in mind

Comment: Strictly speaking, you haven't covered open sets like $(a,b)\cup (c,d)$. OTOH, the empty set is already covered by $(-\infty,b)\cap(a,\infty)$ through the case $a\ge b$.

Comment: Indeed I'm using characterization of continuity by means of basis

Comment: @sinbadh please what is the basis of $(R,|.|)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The system $\mathcal S=\{(-\infty,b), (a,\infty); a,b\in\mathbb R\}$ is a [subbase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subbase) for the usual Euclidean topology on $\mathbb R$. (This means that all elements of $\mathcal S$ are open and if you take intersections of finitely meany elements from $\mathcal S$, you get a basis. And, indeed, such intersections are in this case precisely the open intervals or empty set.)

In general we have the following:

> Let $X$, $Y$ be a topological space, $f\colon X\to Y$ be a function and $\mathcal S$ be a subbase for the $Y$. The function $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(U)$ is open for each $U\in\mathcal S$.

The proof of this fact is not difficult.

> *Proof.* $\boxed{\Rightarrow}$ This implication is clear, since the sets from $\mathcal S$ are open.
>
> $\boxed{\Leftarrow}$ Let $\mathcal B$ be the system of all finite intersections of sets from $\mathcal S$. 
>   If $B\in\mathcal B$ then $B$ has the form
>   $$B=\bigcap_{i=1}^n U_i$$
>   for some $U_i\in\mathcal S$, $i=1,\dots,n$. Since
>   $$f^{-1}[B]=\bigcap_{i=1}^n f^{-1}[U_i],$$
>   we get that $f^{-1}[B]$ is open for each $B\in\mathcal B$.
>
> Now we know that preimages of all basic sets are open. We also know that open sets are precisely unions of sets from $\mathcal B$. So if 
>   $$O=\bigcup_{i\in I} B_i$$
>   for some $\{B_i; i\in I\}\subseteq\mathcal B$, then we see that
>   $$f^{-1}[O]=\bigcup_{i\in I} f^{-1}[B_i]$$
>   is open. $\square$

In the above proof we have used the fact that preimages preserve unions and intersections. See, for example:
[Overview of basic results about images and preimages](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages), [What are the strategies I can use to prove $f^{-1}(S \cap T) = f^{-1}(S) \cap f^{-1}(T)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228711/what-are-the-strategies-i-can-use-to-prove-f-1s-cap-t-f-1s-cap-f), 
[Union of preimages and preimage of union](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141356/union-of-preimages-and-preimage-of-union) (and some other posts.)

Comment: please how to prove that S is a subbasis ?

Comment: is S is basis for (R,|.|)?

Comment: @Vrouvrou [Show that rays of the form $(-\infty, a)$ and $(b, \infty)$ ; $a,b \in \mathbb R$, are a sub-basis for the standard topology on $\mathbb R$?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71693/show-that-rays-of-the-form-infty-a-and-b-infty-a-b-in-mathbb-r) (And probably you can find the proof in many places.)

Comment: @Vrouvrou No, $\mathcal S$ is not a basis. (But it is subbasis.) If you want a basis, you can take, for example, all open intervals; or simply open intervals of the form $(a,b)$.  The system $\mathcal B=\{(a,b); a,b\in\mathbb R, a<b\}$ is a [base](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)) for the standard topology of the real line.

Answer (score 0):

$f$ is continuous if and only if  the preimage by $f$ of ANY open set is open. Then it suffices to remark that $]a, b[= ]a, \infty[ \cap ]-\infty, b[.$